# PowerShell import and sort data from CSV to Automate New-CMBoundary (SCCM)

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach, sccm

I have a CSV which i have processed subnet information in using CONCAT and some other functions. I have address range boundaries and Sites and want to automate the creation of SCCM IP Address Range boundaries using PowerShell and the CSV file and New-CMBoundary cmdlet. Please See below:

- Column B is the Site Code
- Column F Contains the Range e.g. 192.168.1.0-192.168.1.254

Code so far:

```
         'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin'
        Import-Module .\ConfigurationManager.psd1
        cd SCC:

                Get-CMSite

                $subnetranges = import-csv C:\subnets.csv
                $Site = $subnetranges | select -ExpandProperty "Site Code"
                $Range = $subnetranges | select -ExpandProperty "VLAN5 Range"

    ForEach ($subnet in $subnetranges) {

                    New-CMBoundary -DisplayName $Site -BoundaryType IPRange -Value $Range

    }
```

This obviously isn't quite right, Can you see what I'm trying to do? how do i get each row from the CSV into the respective variable but then enumerate through using the ForEach loop? If that is even the best method.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer:

```
#import boundaries
$csv = Import-Csv C:\iprangescsvnew.csv
cd POS:
foreach($line in $csv){

            Write-host "Creating boundary for $($line.subnet)"
            New-CMBoundary -Name $line.'Name' -Type IPRange -Value $line.Value }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, according to this site and chap, pipe the values from a CSV to the NEW-CMBOUNDARY cmdlet.

http://www.dexterposh.com/2014/07/powershell-sccm-2012-boundaries.html

This is the actual video of the working code being ran:
https://youtu.be/jjjigfddkm8

Essentially he just pipes the `import-csv c:\file.csv | new-cmboundary` with 3 values, Name, Type,Value and it works. I've copied this to the T and cannot for love nor money get this to work.Looking at the help for that cmdlet, pipeline input is not accepted. How did he get the pipeline input accepted?